# Using AWS API Gateway SDK in Node.JS causes issues

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

So I am trying to follow the AWS API Gateway SDK tutorial on setting up a secure connection between the NodeJS App and API Gateway [link here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html).

My test function looks like something like below:

```
  require('./lib/apigClient');
  require('./lib/axios/dist/axios.standalone');
  require('./lib/CryptoJS/rollups/hmac-sha256');
  require('./lib/CryptoJS/rollups/sha256');
  require('./lib/CryptoJS/components/hmac');
  require('./lib/CryptoJS/components/enc-base64');
  require('./lib/url-template/url-template');
  require('./lib/apiGatewayCore/sigV4Client');
  require('./lib/apiGatewayCore/apiGatewayClient');
  require('./lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient');
  require('./lib/apiGatewayCore/utils');

var body = {
  "type": "the_best_kind",
  "status": "processed",
  "name": "test123"
};

export function getRatingsTest(req, res) {

  var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    accessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY',
    secretKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
    sessionToken:'SESSION_TOKEn', //OPTIONAL: If you are using temporary credentials you must include the session token
    region: 'eu-west-1' // OPTIONAL: The region where the API is deployed, by default this parameter is set to us-east-1
});
  console.log('NEW CLIENT =====', apigClient)

  apigClient.calcRatingPost(null, body, null)
    .then(function(result){
        //This is where you would put a success callback
    }).catch( function(result){
        //This is where you would put an error callback
    });
  return res.json({test: 123})
}
```

I keep getting error such a apiGateway is not defined, CryptoJs is not defined and so on. All the 11 javascript files are not modular which is unfortunate.

**What is the best approach for getting this to work in NodeJS?**

I also tried the aws-api-gateway-client [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client) but no luck yet.

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution for this as well. In my case, I was exporting the SDK from an AWS APIGateway Stage and was hoping I could just simply share it across a couple React Projects. It seems like the intended use of the SDK is loading this into a web browser only. It also seems like this will take a lot of rewrite to have this work in node.js. In my case, i'm probably better off writing my own JS library to communicate with my API.